# Django: How to get current URLConf rule from a view?

Tags: django

In a Django view, is there a way to get the name of the URLConf rule which triggered activated the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve) the path given in `request.path`.